# C++ Decorate basic_stream::underflow()

Tags: c++, decorator, standard-library, streambuf

I want to extend the behavior of a basic_streambuf object by using the decorator pattern. That`s what I currently got:

```
template<typename char_type, class traits_type>
class forwarding_basic_streambuf
    : boost::noncopyable,
      public std::basic_streambuf<char_type, traits_type>
{
public:
    typedef std::basic_streambuf<char_type, traits_type> forwarded_type;

    forwarding_basic_streambuf(forwarded_type& fwd_buf)
        : m_fwd(&fwd_buf) { }
    virtual ~forwarding_basic_streambuf() { }

    // locales:
//  std::locale pubimbue(std::locale const& loc);
//      => Calls: imbue(loc) | Returns: Previous value of getloc();
//  std::locale getloc  () const;
//      => Returns: If pubimbue() has ever been called, then the last value of loc supplied, otherwise the
//                  current global locale, locale(), in effect at the time of construction. If called after
//                  pubimbue() has been called but before pubimbue has returned (i.e., from within the call
//                  of imbue()) then it returns the previous value.

    // buffer management and positioning:
//  forwarded_type* pubsetbuf (char_type* s, std::streamsize n); => Returns: setbuf(s, n)
//  pos_type        pubseekoff(off_type off, std::ios_base::seekdir way,
//      std::ios_base::openmode which = std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out);
//      => Returns seekoff(off, way, which)
//  pos_type        pubseekpos(pos_type sp,
//      std::ios_base::openmode which = std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out);
//      => Returns: seekpos(sp, which)
//  int             pubsync   (); => Returns: sync()

    // get and put areas:
    // get area:
//  std::streamsize sgetn   (char_type* s, std::streamsize n); => Returns: xsgetn(s, n)

    // put area:
//  std::streamsize sputn(char_type const* s, std::streamsize n); => Returns: xsputn(s, n)

protected:
    // virtual functions:
    // locales:
    virtual void imbue(std::locale const& loc) { this->m_fwd->pubimbue(loc); }

    // buffer management and positioning:
    virtual forwarded_type*  setbuf (char_type* s, std::streamsize n)
        { return this->m_fwd->pubsetbuf(s, n); }
    virtual pos_type         seekoff(off_type off, std::ios_base::seekdir way,
        std::ios_base::openmode which = std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out)
        { return this->m_fwd->pubseekoff(off, way); }
    virtual pos_type         seekpos(pos_type sp,
        std::ios_base::openmode which = std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out)
        { return this->m_fwd->pubseekpos(sp, which); }
    virtual int              sync   ()
        { return this->m_fwd->pubsync(); }

    // get and put areas:
    // get area:
    virtual std::streamsize xsgetn(char_type* s, std::streamsize n)
        { return this->m_fwd->sgetn(s, n); }
    virtual int_type        uflow()
        {
            if (traits_type::eq_int_type(this->underflow(), traits_type::eof()))
                return traits_type::eof();
            return this->m_fwd->sgetc();
        }

    // put area:
    virtual std::streamsize xsputn  (char_type const* s, std::streamsize n)
        { return this->m_fwd->sputn(s, n); }
    virtual int_type        overflow(int_type c = traits_type::eof())
        {
            if (traits_type::eq_int_type(c, traits_type::eof()))
                return traits_type::not_eof(c);
            return this->m_fwd->sputc(traits_type::to_char_type(c));
        }

private:
    forwarded_type* m_fwd;
};
```

The basic goal (as a first step) would be to simply forward each functionality to the decorated object. Thus, it should be possible to use this decorater even with a pointer to it`s base class.

That all works fine for writing methods, but I don`t know how to deal with the underflow() function, which is called from uflow() and sgetc().

Comment: Why don't you just forwarding the virtual functions to the forwarded type, why re-implement them? There's no point in hiding the base class versions of the non-virtual functions as they won't be use by anyone using a pointer or reference to your base class: `std::basic_streambuf`.

Comment: @Charles Bailes - Sorry for that. Fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

I might be missing something but your design doesn't make much sense to me.

As I see it, extending a `streambuf` is done by overriding the protected virtual interface, if you'd want to use a decorator pattern your decorator base class would do just that.

```
template<typename char_type, class traits_type>
class forwarding_basic_streambuf
    : boost::noncopyable,
      public std::basic_streambuf<char_type, traits_type>
{
public:
    typedef std::basic_streambuf<char_type, traits_type> forwarded_type;

    forwarding_basic_streambuf(forwarded_type& fwd_buf)
        : m_fwd(&fwd_buf) { }
    virtual ~forwarding_basic_streambuf() { }

protected:
   virtual streamsize xsputn ( const char * s, streamsize n ) {
       m_fwd->xsputn(s,n);
   }
   virtual int overflow ( int c) {
       m_fwd->overflow(c);
   }
   // etc.
};
```

You real implementation would then add any needed 'decorations' e.g.

```
template<typename char_type, class traits_type>
class add_timestamp_decorator
    : public forwarding_basic_streambuf<char_type, traits_type>
{
public:
    typedef std::forwarding_basic_streambuf<char_type, traits_type> base_type;

    add_timestamp_decorator(base_type::forwarded_type& fwd_buf)
        : base_type(&fwd_buf) { }
    virtual ~add_timestamp_decorator() { }

protected:
   virtual streamsize xsputn ( const char * s, streamsize n ) {
       // detect and remember when a newline is written
       // before the next char is written output the timestamp
       base_type::xsputn(s, n);
   }
   // etc.
};
```

And then use it on an outputstream (pseudo code, omitted template definitions for clarity)

```
ostream outputstream;
// ....
add_timestamp_decorator decorator = new add_timestamp_decorator(outputstream.rdbuf());
outputstream.rdbuf(decorator);

outputstream << "some lines\ntimestamps will be inserted\n\n";
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That usage could lead into unintended behavior. Please consider a situation where you want to do something before it`s actually `read` from the underlying device. You could use `sbumpc` to read a single character at a time. However, that won`t do what it should. So, I would need to override `uflow` in a way I showed in my answer. I omitted any decorating code for simplicity. But I want to use my decorator as if it were the decorated object itself.

Comment: Btw: `overflow()` and `underflow` will be called all the time when you read or write by using the decorator, because it`s own read/write buffer is always empty.

Comment: @FrEEzE2046 If you want to fundamentally change the underlying behaviour, I don't think you should use the decorator pattern, but simply create a subclass and override / change the behaviour of the class

Comment: I don't want to fundamentally change the behavior. Quite the contrary: The behavior should be exactly the same. The only difference are the few methods I want to decorate. For clarity: If I would only handle write operations (maybe because they are what I'm interested in) and don't care about the read operations, I could not use the decorator in a scenario where the implementations needs to read from that streambuf, because the read operations wouldn't been forwarded to the decorated object.

Answer (score 0):

The specification describes `uflow()` in the following way (27.6.3.4.3.[15-17]):

- Requires: The constraints are the same as for underflow(), except that the result character be transferred from the pending sequence to the backup sequence, and the pending sequence shall not be empty before the transfer.
- Default behavior: Calls underflow(). If underflow() returns traits::eof(), returns traits::eof(). Otherwise, returns the value of traits::to_int_type(*gptr()) and increment the value of the next pointer for the input sequence.
- Returns: traits::eof() to indicate failure.

In C++, this look would look like:

```
if (traits::eq_int_type(this->underflow(), traits::eof())
    return traits::eof();    
return *fetch_gptr_and_inc();
```

We cannot call `underflow()` on the decorated object directly, because it's not accessible.
In addition, we don't want to fetch our own gptr(), but the decorated one.
However, we can achieve this indirectly by calling `sgetc()` and `sbumpc`:

```
template<typename char_type, class traits_type>
typename forwarding_basic_streambuf<char_type, traits_type>::int_type
forwarding_basic_streambuf<char_type, traits_type>::uflow()
{   
    if (traits_type::eq_int_type(this->m_fwd->sgetc(), traits_type::eof()))
        return traits_type::eof();
    return this->m_fwd->sbumpc();
}
```